# Can the Windows client os be used as a VPN server?

Tags: windows, vpn

The Windows client operating systems ([XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314076), Vista, Windows 7) can connect to a remote VPN server.  Can the Windows client operating systems be used as a VPN server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you can.

There are various blogs for [XP](http://www.aeonity.com/frost/howto-windows-xp-vpn-server-setup), [Vista and Windows 7](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/vista_vpn_server.htm) with full instructions on how to set it up.  Functionality is already built into Windows, it's just knowing where to find it and switch it on.

Each link shows different instructions for each OS.

Answer (score 3):

but of course ...

[**Configure Windows XP Professional to be a VPN server**](http://www.zdnetasia.com/insight/network/0,39044847,39050037-39000223c-1,00.htm)